# how to read nested json objects in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have json string

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 78,
        "max_score": 1.5,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "S3",
                "_type": "se",
                "_id": "00CD03",
                "_score": 1.5,
                "contact": {
                    "defaultAddress": {
                        "addressLine1": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                        "addressLine2": null,
                        "addressCode": null,
                        "geoLocation": {
                            "lon": "14.1514",
                            "lat": "16.7555"
                        },
                    },
                    "defaultEmail": "aaaa.bbbb@gmail.in",
                    "defaultPhoneNumber": "080 1140 637",
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "S3",
                "_type": "se",
                "_id": "00C3D0-01260-3",
                "_score": 1.5,
                "contact": {
                    "defaultAddress": {
                        "addressLine1": "bbbbbbbbbb 1",
                        "addressLine2": "ggggggggg",
                        "addressCode": null,
                        "geoLocation": {
                            "lon": "97.1511101",
                            "lat": "15.7888899"
                        },
                    },
                    "defaultEmail": "kkkkk@yahoo.de",
                    "defaultPhoneNumber": "0909 140 637",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

need to loop through the json and create a list details in C#. Looking for help

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: create a List<Contact>.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this by any chance an ElasticSearch search result? If it is, why aren't you just using the NEST C# driver to make your query?

Comment: var childrenTokens = ((JToken)hits).Children().ToList();

Comment: If you wish to show what you've tried so far, please _edit the question_ to provide that code (as an [mcve]) please.

Comment: yes, its Elasticsearch result

Comment: Just use the [NEST driver](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) - it takes care of all the JSON request/response serialization stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

@NLSrini

You can use the nugget package "[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)". Then you can create an class Object that represents your JSON structure and to deserialize you can use: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json);`

You can see for more examples here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: To create you class more easily you can use the online parser JSON to C# class: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: It is even easier to let Visual Studio handle it